# Flatten an array of arrays in postgres to a single array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Given something such as the following:

```
select array[array[1, 2], array[3, 4]]
```

Which returns

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

I would like to know how to flatten this to a single array as:

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to achieve it:

```
select array(select unnest(array[array[1, 2], array[3, 4]]));
```

Result:

```
{1,2,3,4}
```